# CSS Ignoring font face

Tags: css, fonts

I am putting together a website in codeIgniter, but I'm having some trouble with the CSS

The below code is giving me a serif font - I know the stylesheet's properly linked because the text fits all the other parameters, and changes when I unlink it.

```
span.navbig {
    font-size: 36pt;
    font-family: Gill Sans / Gill Sans MT, sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: -1.5pt;
    text-decoration: none;   
}
```

What am I not seeing here?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Separate thefont types in your font-family declaration different, something like this:

```
font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", sans-serif;
```

[Here's](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_font-family.asp) some easy reference:

> **Note:** Separate each value with a comma.
>
> **Note:** If a font name contains white-space, it must be quoted.
>   Single quotes must be used when using the "style" attribute in HTML.

And [here's](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/fonts.html#propdef-font-family) the W3C recommendation:

> Font family names must either be given quoted as strings, or unquoted
>   as a sequence of one or more identifiers. This means most punctuation
>   characters and digits at the start of each token must be escaped in
>   unquoted font family names.

Answer (score 2):

When using FONT types that consist of two words, quotes must be placed on them so the browser does not read them as separate entries.

```
<style type="text/css">
    span.navbig {
      font-size: 36pt;
      font-family: "gill sans", sans-serif;
      letter-spacing: -1.5pt;
      text-decoration: none;   
    }
</style>
```

from http://www.htmlite.com/CSS004.php